# How to turn off the Windows 10 auto-suggest feature in a WPF application?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-10, autosuggest

I'm creating a special GLSL Editor for my own needs in WPF. In Windows 10, I've enabled the show-text-suggestions-as-I-type a long time ago.

[image: Text-suggestions feature]
It's a useful feature but not in a **code** editor application so I tried turning it off just for the editing TextBox without disabling it for the whole system like Notepad++.

```
<RichTextBox SpellCheck.IsEnabled="False"/>
```

**I still get**

[image: Windows 10 is still checking the RichTextBox]

I'm still new to WPF so sorry if this property has nothing to do, I tried googling a lot and I get only for the whole Windows 10 or for building an auto-complete TextBox.

So, how can I turn it off for just that RichTextBox without turning it off for the **whole** Windows?

**Edit:**
The code above just removes the spell-checking however I can't find any for the auto-suggesting.

Comment: Is it mobile platform or what is it? On my pc spell checking is only red underline and I have to invoke context menu to see suggestions. And it's off by default for `RichTextBox`, so I can't reproduce the issue.

Comment: @Sinatr I edited my question to correct it some minutes ago, I'm using PC, there's a feature in Windows 10 that shows text suggestions as you type in a TextBox, I think someway it's useless in my code editor application so I wanted to turn it off just like Notepad++ but I don't know how since I'm new to WPF. (not spell-checking, sorry)

Comment: *"there's a feature in Windows 10 that shows text suggestions as you type in a TextBox"* - what feature? I've no clue about what is it (would be nice if you add a link to it) and it looks like you want to disable that feature and not `SpellCheck`, so setting `IsEnabled = false` won't do anything.

Comment: Yes, I want to disable this feature, but not for the whole Windows 10. I want to turn that feature off for just a single TextBox in my WPF application like Notepad++. I said spell-checking because they looked the same for me and I didn't find text-suggestions tag, sorry again.

Comment: I edited the question, you're right that `SpellCheck.IsEnabled="False"` won't do any for the auto-suggest feature but isn't there any alternative property?

Comment: I doubt wpf supports some windows 10 setting. Rather it's other way: windows *detects* what you are inputting text. Not sure how. Maybe via accessibility or caret. And then windows draws that popup with suggestions. How to prevent that popup? By preventing text input to go *standard* way. But if you do so - you may interfere with other things, e.g. your code editor become useless for impaired people. And real question is why you want to do it? Performance? I doubt windows-wide feature would be so bad. Performance problem is elsewhere.

Comment: The suggestions are still useful if you decide to type a text into your code editor, aren't they?

Comment: No, not performance issue anymore, there's just no need for an auto-suggest feature in a Code Editor. I may implement my own **auto-completion** for GLSL keywords but such a thing as auto-suggested words popping up each letter will just annoy me naming my variables and using the standard language keywords as shown in the pic above. Can't I just use C# procedural code to turn it off? Notepad++ doesn't have that annoying feature even if it's turned on in the system. If it can then I can too, but how? I know Notepad++ isn't a WPF application but that doesn't mean it's not possible in WPF.